# Земля была безвидна и пуста

Tags: славянизмы, устаревшие-слова, лексика

В начале Библии есть такие слова:

*"Земля же была **безвидна** и пуста, и тьма над бездною..."*

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает слово *"безвидна"* ?

**P.S.** Мне сразу представляются космические фотографии других планет, пустых и жутковато безжизненных.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем ломать копья, если Ваши ответы не противоречат друг другу? Без вида = бесформенный = неприглядный. Бесформенное всегда неприглядно:

БЕЗВИДНЫЙ в толковом словаре Даля: невидный, неказистый, невзрачный.
Безвидность товара незаманчива.

Словарь устаревших слов: БЕЗВИДНЫЙ — не имеющий вида, образа.

[УСТАРЕВШИЕ И МАЛОПОНЯТНЫЕ СЛОВА](http://jesuschrist2012.narod.ru/books/stslov.htm)

Но здесь имеется в виду самое первое значение слова — вид — то, что видно, воспринимается зрением, а там было всё безвидно, не воспринимаемо зрением — ни формы, ни вида — и пустынность, безжизненность, и неприглядность, и то, что ещё не было суши и воды, не было света, поэтому всё сливалось.
Бог носился над тёмной водою и называл землёй всё водное пространство. Тогда он создал только небо и землю, но земля не отличалась от тьмы над бездной, у неё не было собственного вида, тогда он создал свет, свет стал днём, а тьма ночью, потом он создал твердь небесную и твердь земную. Тогда твердь земная, суша, и стала той землёю, которую мы имеем в виду, она стала видной, отличаемой от неба, от воды океана и морей.

Comment: >Зачем ломать копья, если Ваши ответы не противоречат друг другу?   

Они в корне противоречат. Вы домысливаете с чем я никак не могу соглачиться. 

Что касается Даля, то даже без учета известного к нему отношения большинства филологов, не могу найти указаний на то, что он своё значение распросространял на канонические тексты.

Comment: Вы  как  с  богом  рядом  стояли,  наблюдали  как  всё  происходило  и  нам  пересказали.  А  всё  равно  ясной  картинки  не  получается.  Если  бы  этот  текст  нарисовать  в  виде  комикса  то  всё,  что  было  до  создания  света  изобразить  невозможно,  а  потом  уже  хоть  и  пустынно,  но  видно.  Но  может  неприглядно.  А  вот  как  эта  неприглядность  выглядела,  попробуйте  нарисуйте.  Если,  как  вы  говорите,  у  неё  не  было  собственного  вида.

Answer (score 6):

Я не знаю ответа правильного, но предположение такое: БЕЗВИДНАЯ - БЕЗ ВИДА, неприглядная, невзрачная, ничего на ней нет привлекающего взор, а может и совсем ничего нет.

Comment: Спасибо. +1

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае "безвидна" означает невидима. Именно так переводится греческое "éÒratow" на русский язык ( [см. построчный перевод с греческого](http://ihtys.narod.ru/01_gen.pdf)). В Елисаветинском переводе на ЦСЯ, который до сих пор является основным для священиков РПЦ, переведено именно так ("Земля же была невидима и не устроена") . Сомнительно, чтобы в Синодальном переводе подразумевали что-либо другое.

В [иудейском переводе](http://www.toraonline.ru/bereyshis/bereyshis.htm), Мосад рав Кук перевёл  фразу следующим образом.

> Земля же была пуста и хаотична, и тьма
> над бездною; и дух Б-жий витал над
> водою.

Видимо с этим же пониманием и связано использование в Библии короля Якова и Вульгате значения бесформенная.

Как фразу интерпретировать вопрос спорный. Во-первых, можно
предположить, что это всего  лишь констатация  факта. "В начале сотворил Бог
небо и  землю" -  и все  это было  "безвидным и пустым", сотворенным, таким
образом,  из  ничего. Во-вторых,  можно допустить также, что первый стих  -
краткая сводка, конспект,  нечто вроде названия первой  главы - "Сотворение
неба и земли"; в  этом случае должно последовать  подробное изложение, как и
что было сделано.  Первый вариант интерпритации характерен для Восточнохристианских церквей, второй - для Западных.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный ответ. +1

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего сравнить с любым переводом. 
And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
(KJ, Gen,1:2)

Ни о какой "неприглядности" речи нет. Земля **не имела вида**, т.е. была бесформенной.

Comment: Наверное, полагаться на переводы Библии не надо, потому что каждый автор перевода трактует если не слово в слово, то по своему восприятию, пониманию текста. Читая переводы поэзии Т.Г.Шевченко, диву даешься, почему они такие разные, хотя оригинал колоритнее и понятнее. Так что спорный вопрос:БЕЗВИДНЫЙ - это неприглядный или бесформенный (а вообще-то, как можно определить бесформенность, не видя предмет целиком!)

Comment: Тогда нужно обращаться к оригиналу: или на иврите, или к Септуагинте.

Comment: Тогда о каком значении мы говорим, если счтать, что "авторы" привнесли отсебятину?! На этом осчновании можно оспорить вообще любой текст.
 
Да и вообще в отношении Библии разговоры о превеводческом произволе. Мало тгого, что тексты канонизированы, так еще и они с одного источника сделаны. И еще вы забываете, чт о таких переводов - миллион. Есть с чем сравнивать.

Comment: >тексты канонизированы, так еще и они с одного источника сделаны.

Совершенно верно. Переводы Библии -- это как правило серьёзные переводы, сделанные со стремлением максимально точно передать значение оригинального текста. Я видел один украинский перевод Евангелия, так там в тех местах, где попадались неоднозначно понимаемые слова, в примечаниях давались и церковно-славянские, и греческие варианты с объяснениями.

А переводы стихов -- они более вольные. В стихах зачастую передаётся не столько информация, сколько эмоциональное состояние.

Comment: Так каждый перевод - это отчасти отсебятина. То, что в Библии произвол переводческий - это всем ведомо. Потому то и разные трактовки одного и того же. Даже фильмы разные по одному и тому же сценарию (к примеру, по Достоевскому "Идио" В. Бортко и В.Пырьева). А вы спорите об анг. трактовке. И Шевченко тут ни при чем. Его произведения переводят до сих пор, и все они разные: чувствуют, понимают тексты каждый по своему.

Comment: Думаю, речь идёт об ощутимо *разном проценте* отсебятины. В технических переводах -- минимальный. В религиозных, если, подчёркиваю, в рамках одной и той же конфессии, то тоже небольшой, т.к. существуют определённые строгие каноны. У католиков, к примеру, одни, а у, допустим, свидетелей Иеговы, в какой-то степени, другие.

В переводах стихов этот процент отсебятины можно и повысить. Тем более надо выдержать размер и рифму.

А сценарии по книгам для театра и кино -- тут уж такая свобода творчества! Иногда меняют до неузнаваемости!

Comment: >А вы спорите об анг. трактовке.

Я не спорю. Ответ на вопрос уже для меня понятен. 
Без вида, не имела вида, без формы (англ. without form), неприглядна, не воспринимаема зрением.

Всем большое спасибо за объяснения! :) Всем ответившим плюсую.

Comment: >То, что в Библии произвол переводческий - это всем ведомо.  

Уууу... А давайте не будем говорить бездоказательно подобного?!
Разночтения в переводах известны и хорошо укладываются в общую схему.
Но онеи не стольт вопиющи, что сеняется смысл едва ли не на противоположный. 
Что же касается возможных ошибок, то я и предлагаю обратиться к более достоверным источникам, подтверждающими друг друга. 
Не нроавится Кинг Джейс -  читайте Вульгату. 
**terra autem erat inanis et vacua et tenebrae super faciem abyssi et spiritus Dei ferebatur super aquas**

 inanis - бесформенный, никак не неприглядный.

Answer (score 2):

Слова «безвидна и пуста», которыми характеризуется первобытная масса, заключают в себе мысль о «тьме, беспорядке и разрушении» (Ис 40:17; 45:18; Иер 4:23–26),т. е. дают идею о состоянии полного хаоса, в котором элементы будущего света, воздуха, земли, воды и также все зародыши растительной и животной жизни не поддавались еще никакому различению и были как бы перемешаны между собой. Лучшей параллелью к этим словам служит место из книги Премудростей Соломона, в котором говорится, что Бог сотворил мир из «необразного вещества» 11:18)и 2 Пет 3:5.

http://smartbible.narod.ru/bvz/01/Bytie01.htm#st02

Comment: @gecube, я сделал комментарий ответом, он того стоит. 
Если есть возражения, верну как было, не вопрос.

Comment: Тут  цепочка  из  нескольких  языков  в  интервале  нескольких  тысячелетий,  да  ещё  и  в  поэтическом,  фактически,  тексте,  а вы ещё  точности  хотите !